# Define Router Link in Vuetify v-list in Google Contact Template

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-router

I am new to Vuetify and I am having no idea on how to use router link in v-list in the Google Contact Template provided by vuetiy. The list is binded with the data attribute inside script tag. How can I add router links to it?

This is the **v-list** inside **template** tag.

```
 <v-list dense>
        <template v-for="item in items">
          <v-row
            v-if="item.heading"
            :key="item.heading"
            align="center"
          >
            <v-col cols="6">
              <v-subheader v-if="item.heading">
                {{ item.heading }}
              </v-subheader>
            </v-col>
            <v-col
              cols="6"
              class="text-center"
            >
              <a
                href="#!"
                class="body-2 black--text"
              >EDIT</a>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-list-group
            v-else-if="item.children"
            :key="item.text"
            v-model="item.model"
            :prepend-icon="item.model ? item.icon : item['icon-alt']"
            append-icon=""
          >
            <template v-slot:activator>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>
                  {{ item.text }}
                </v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </template>
            <v-list-item
              v-for="(child, i) in item.children"
              :key="i"
              link
            >
              <v-list-item-action v-if="child.icon">
                <v-icon>{{ child.icon }}</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>
                  {{ child.text }}
                </v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-group>
          <v-list-item
            v-else
            :key="item.text"
            link
          >
            <v-list-item-action>
              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-action>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>
                {{ item.text }}
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </template>
      </v-list>
```

This is the script tag

```
data: () => ({
      dialog: false,
      drawer: null,
      items: [
        { icon: 'mdi-contacts', text: 'Contacts' },
        { icon: 'mdi-history', text: 'Frequently contacted' },
        { icon: 'mdi-content-copy', text: 'Duplicates' },
        {
          icon: 'mdi-chevron-up',
          'icon-alt': 'mdi-chevron-down',
          text: 'Labels',
          model: true,
          children: [
            { icon: 'mdi-plus', text: 'Create label' },
          ],
        },
        {
          icon: 'mdi-chevron-up',
          'icon-alt': 'mdi-chevron-down',
          text: 'More',
          model: false,
          children: [
            { text: 'Import' },
            { text: 'Export' },
            { text: 'Print' },
            { text: 'Undo changes' },
            { text: 'Other contacts' },
          ],
        },
        { icon: 'mdi-settings', text: 'Settings' },
        { icon: 'mdi-message', text: 'Send feedback' },
        { icon: 'mdi-help-circle', text: 'Help' },
        { icon: 'mdi-cellphone-link', text: 'App downloads' },
        { icon: 'mdi-keyboard', text: 'Go to the old version' },
      ],
    }),
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the route path to a key in the items, for example a key named `to`...

```
items: [
     { icon: 'mdi-contacts', text: 'Contacts', to: '/contacts' },
     { icon: 'mdi-history', text: 'Frequently contacted', to: '/route2'  },
     { icon: 'mdi-content-copy', text: 'Duplicates', to: '/route3' },
     ...
]
```

Then, pass that key value to the `:to` prop in the `v-list-item`...

```
    <v-list-item
        v-else
        :key="item.text"
        :to="item.to?item.to:null"
      >
        <v-list-item-action>
          <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
        </v-list-item-action>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>
            {{ item.text }}
          </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/M1bEQTWUGo)